# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo (even though MainActivity works)

Tags: android, fatal-error

I've searched StackOverflow and Googled the error, but none of the suggested solutions work for me. Most of the problems occur for people in MainActivity, but my MainActivity works fine. The issue comes up when trying to launch other activities. Here is the stack trace:

```
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.news_app/com.example.news_app.android.ui.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at com.example.news_app.android.ui.SettingsActivity.<init>(SettingsActivity.java:12)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
07-24 19:12:14.136: E/AndroidRuntime(20372):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.news_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".android.ui.MainActivityNew" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".android.ui.NewPostActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".android.ui.PostDetailsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".android.ui.SettingsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".android.ui.UserDetailsActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the portion of MainActivity where I launch the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_new_post:
        intent = new Intent(this, NewPostActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is SettingsActivity:

```
package com.example.news_app.android.ui;

import com.example.news_app.R;
import com.example.news_app.android.Settings;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    private Settings appSettings = new Settings(this);
    private EditText editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    private EditText editTextAbout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAbout);
    private EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    private EditText editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        editTextName.setText(appSettings.getName());
        editTextAbout.setText(appSettings.getAbout());
        editTextEmail.setText(appSettings.getEmail());
        editTextPhone.setText(appSettings.getPhone());
    }

    protected void onButtonSaveClick(View view) {
        appSettings.setName(editTextName.getText().toString());
        appSettings.setAbout(editTextAbout.getText().toString());
        appSettings.setEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        appSettings.setPhone(editTextPhone.getText().toString());
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Here is your problem you are finding the view without inflating the layout

```
    private EditText editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
private EditText editTextAbout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAbout);
private EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
private EditText editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
```

These should be declared after you use `setContentView` in oncreate. You can do this to achieve this; Declare the views like this

```
private EditText editTextAbout; 
private EditText editTextEmail; 
private EditText editTextPhone;
```

And then in onCreate after you call setContentView add these

```
editTextAbout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAbout);
editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No luck, unfortunately. Could something else be causing it?

Comment: can you post the whole main activity, It showing the problem is in SettingsActivity line 12, which line is in line 12

Comment: I've added it. The class is technically called MainActivityNew, but that doesn't make a difference since MainActivityNew works.

Comment: Your SettingsActivity works just like what you have in the question?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! I spent hours trying to figure that out. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I just did. Thank you again.